# Opencart disable Quantity in Product Options

Tags: php, opencart

Friends i am stuck with a big problem in Opencart Version 1.5.3.1 and badly need your help.

I added option for "Color" for my product and for each color Opencart requires to tell its Quantity. My client have thousands of products with no issue of stock/quantity.

Its very irritating for them to keep on inserting some numeric value for each color in each product ... not forgetting most of the products have 5 to 15 colors.

Is been 3 days i am searching codes and trying but so far i am unable to find how to disable that.
Problem is if quantity is not inserted then it will not show that color.

I found this code in controller/product/product.php but it solved nothing

```
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) { ...
```

I changed it to:

```
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
if (!$option_value['subtract']) {...
```

Kindly help me solve this issue, it would be a great favor.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `system/library/cart.php`

Find this code around lines 67-69

```
if ($option_value_query->row['subtract'] && (!$option_value_query->row['quantity'] || ($option_value_query->row['quantity'] < $quantity))) {
    $stock = false;
}
```

and either remove them, comment them out or change false to true

Comment: thanks a million my friend, it solved the problem ... once again Big thanks

Comment: There is one problem :( ater removing these lines from cart.php, the options i.e. colors are showing even when quantity is empty i.e. zero. BUT once that product is sold then that specific color quantity becomes in negative and then it again hides that specific color on product page :((

Comment: Not really sure how that could happen really, the edit doesn't affect counts, or even an options status, just means it's not taken into consideration for stock checking